# Dynamically pull query in FLASK

Tags: python, flask

I have a small application built in flask and also I am new to it and hence learning it
Appreciate if you could help me solve below ask.

Right now, the all contents in the dataframe(2 rows) are displayed. Is there a way to display only what is selected in the dropdown(say 'Karan' so only row with Karan should be displayed)

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc 
import urllib

##conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native client 11.0};server=localhost;database=Nifty;trusted_connection=yes;')

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=localhost;"
                                 "DATABASE=Nifty;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = sal.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
##sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('select  top 1 * from [dbo].ABC', engine)

app = Flask(__name__)

read_df = pd.read_excel('List_500_companies.xlsx') ## getting list r
#list_ticker = read_df['symbol'].tolist()
list_ticker = ['Karan', 'Rohit']


## Getting column names from DB

data_values = [['Karan',23],['Rohit',22]]
col_names = pd.DataFrame(data_values,columns=['Name','Age'])


#col_names = pd.read_sql_query('select  top 5 * from [dbo].[3MINDIA]', engine)


headings = col_names
data = col_names.values



@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown():
    get_list_name = list_ticker
    return render_template('template.html', tickers = get_list_name, heading_name = headings, data_name = data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 8080)
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<select onchange="update_selected_option_value(value)">
    {% for ticker in tickers %}<option value="{{ticker}}" SELECTED>{{ticker}}</option>{% endfor %}
</select>
<br></br>



<table>
  <tr>{% for header in heading_name %}<th>{{header}}</th>{% endfor %}</tr>
  {% for row in data_name %}<tr>{% for cell in row %}<td>{{cell}}</td>{% endfor %}</tr>{% endfor %}
</table>


<script>function update_selected_option_value(value) {
  document.getElementById('res_head').innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById('res_data').innerHTML = value;
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows you how you can use the form data transmitted via a GET request to filter your DataFrame.
The user can select several entries from a list of names and submit the form. All selected entries are now queried on the server side using the name of the form field. Then the rows of the DataFrame are filtered in which the "Name" column occurs within the list of selected entries. All resulting rows are displayed.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Karan', 23],
        ['Rohit', 22]
    ],
    columns=['Name', 'Age']
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    names = df['Name'].tolist()

    tickers = request.args.getlist('tickers') or names
    data = df[df['Name'].isin(tickers)]

    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="tickers" multiple>
            {% for name in names -%}
            <option value="{{ name }}" {% if name in tickers -%}selected{% endif -%}>{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <hr />

    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in data.columns -%}
                <th>{{ column }}</th>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in data.values -%}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in row -%}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
            {% endfor -%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you want to use POST as the request method, the example looks like this.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Karan', 23],
        ['Rohit', 22]
    ],
    columns=['Name','Age']
)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    names = df['Name'].tolist()
    tickers = names
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tickers = request.form.getlist('tickers') or names
    data = df[df['Name'].isin(tickers)]
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <select name="tickers" multiple>
            {% for name in names -%}
            <option value="{{ name }}" {% if name in tickers -%}selected{% endif -%}>{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <hr />

    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for column in data.columns -%}
                <th>{{ column }}</th>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in data.values -%}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in row -%}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
            {% endfor -%}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great.. thanks... But may i know what is ````**locals()````?

Comment: [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) returns a dictionary of local variables and their values. This is extended by the two asterisks, so that the key-value pairs are passed as parameters. The expression corresponds to `render_template('index.html', names=names, tickers=tickers, data=data)`.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution helps a lot... I still do not know when to use ````request.args.getlist````, ````request.form````, ````request.form.get````. Is there any material which explains on this?

Comment: Hey i observed one things, whenever we click on submit, the url changes.. Why so? we have not given any GET request anywhere right? Can we make sure the URL does not change , i mean just ````http://XXX.X.X.X:8080/````

Comment: `reuqest.args` is used for URL parameters. These parameters are appended to the URL and are visible to the user. If no method is specified in a form, a GET request with URL parameters is used. `request.form`, on the other hand, is used for form data that is sent via POST request. The data is sent in the request body. `.get(...)` retrieves exactly one value by name, while `.getlist(...)` retrieves multiple values with the same name, which are then returned as a list.

Comment: Got it thanks.. Is there a way to not update the URL? Like not GET request

Comment: I've added a variant to my answer that uses a POST request.

Comment: Brilliant thanks.... I assume post never updates the URL right?

Comment: That is correct.